# rotate UIImage and nothing displays

Tags: iphone

I used the codes below to rotate an UIImage

```
double angle = -90;
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:sss];
UIImage *image =[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
CGSize s = {image.size.width, image.size.height};
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(s);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0,image.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, 2*M_PI*angle/360);
CGContextDrawImage(ctx,CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width, image.size.height),image.CGImage);
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[myUIImageView  setImage:newImage];
```

but nothing displays on myUIImageView.

If there is anything wrong?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to be rotating the image 90 degrees, you should swap the width and height when you create the image context:

```
CGSize s = {image.size.height, image.size.width};
```

This way, there's enough space to draw the fully-transformed image. Attempting to draw an image into a rectangle which exceeds the bounds of a graphics context will just result in nothing being drawn.

P.S. I recommend using a [CGBitmapContext](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html) instead of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()`, as the former is thread-safe, which means you'd be able to do your image manipulations on a background thread if you so chose.

Comment: Yes, I want to draw an the rotated image to a rectangle, how to display all rotated image?